# Disable accent on mac

Tags: macos

Whenever I type `^` or ` or `~` etc... I don't get the character right away, the system is actually waiting for me to type a letter and then accentuate it. It's very annoying, how can I turn that off?

Comment: What Input Source do you have set? This is not default behaviour. Default is that you must first intentionally use a 'dead key' then a letter, to produce an accented letter. e.g. Opt/n then n will give ñ, whereas just pressing tilde will give tilde ~

Comment: Right I was using US - International instead of US... Thanks!